# Cant connect to RDS instance created with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

Hey y'all I've just created an RDS instance via elastic beanstalk, currently using a VPC security group. I've allowed all inbound traffic via the RDS VPC security group but still get an error attempting to connect via mysql on the command line.

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'http://example.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
```

I'm following the steps shown here and connecting via port 3306: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Although for some reason it is just not connecting.Any ideas?

Comment: You are running the mysql command line on an AWS instance?

Comment: no from the command line on my personal mac, I haven't SSH'd into the instance

Comment: Ssh in or use ssh port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

The instance will need to be in a publicly accessible subnet, and also have the 'publicly accessible' flag enabled, as well as opening the port from your IP address.

Comment: This would open up security issues. If both the Elastic Beanstalk and RDS instances are in the same VPC then you don't want and don't need to make the RDS instance publicly accessible. You only need to make it publicly accessible if you are accessing it from outside AWS.

Comment: Yes, it's not as secure, but the OP wants to access the instance from outside the VPC, so there is no choice

Comment: There is a choice. SSH port forwarding.

Comment: Well, yes, but that implies launching a publicly accessible EC2 instance as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen this question, I hope the answer is still relevant to you. Probably you can check the security group of the RDS instance to see if the port 3306 is open to the Security Group of Elastic Beanstalk instance.